# Can't play an Audio clip stored in an audio in Android (Must be turned to String)

Tags: java, android, audio

I can't seem to get my audio file to replay as the file output won't accept the given argument.

Here's the code:

```
final File output = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());
```

Problem is I can't replay the audio I store in that file (that is the "output" file).
I tried to use this:

```
MediaPlayer replayer = new MediaPlayer(getClass().getResource(output));
replayer.play();
```

I'm using this with an onclicklistener, but I run into the error:
"The argument is not valid for this type(file)" And when I turn it to a String file, then the rest of my code turns up bugged.

Thanks for helping. I'm relatively new to Android development so I'm opened to all suggestions.

Comment: Among other problems, the root directory of the external storage, while technically a "File" is really a directory, not a "file" you can store data in.  You need to create a file *within* the directory for your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Uri.parse` to pass audio path including file name to MediaPlayer constructor as:

```
MediaPlayer replayer = 
         MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse(output+ "yourfilename.xxx"));
replayer.start();
```